# Trouble raising an exception using try and except

Tags: python, python-3.x, except

I am trying to raise an exception when an invalid role is given to my function. My code is as follows

```
    def __init__(self, role, name, health):
        try:
            if role == 'Grooble' or role == 'Throve' or role == 'Plaguelet':
                self.role = str(role)
        
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Whosit role")
```

And the test is

```
try:
    oof = Whosit('Famine', 'Fred', 0)
    print("Did you forget to raise an exception?")
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Famine is an invalid role but I am struggling to get my code to see this ValueError and print "Invalid Whosit role"

Comment: Note that you may want to use an `enum` to represent roles in this case. However, `except` only runs if an exception is raised. An `if` statement evaluating to `False` does not raise an exception. Just use `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just nothing in your `__init__` that would raise a `ValueError`, so the `except ValueError` clause will never run. If `role` doesn't match `Grooble`, `Throve` or `Plaguelet`, `self.role` won't be set, but that's about it. IISC you want a `ValueError` to be raised if the `role` doesn't match, so you'll have to do that yourself:

```
    def __init__(self, role, name, health):
        if role in ['Grooble', 'Throve', 'Plaguelet']:
            self.role = str(role)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid Whosit role")
```

Note that I also simplified the check for `role` a bit ;)

Comment: I tried this but now it also prints "Did you forget to raise an exception?" after it prints "Invalid Whosit role".

Comment: remove the "try", it hides the exception. It is also an invalid syntax, try need an except.